# I don't know the scope of var

Tags: javascript, scope

I want to make a table with vanilla js. But I got a different result depending on where I declare the var.

```js
var body = document.body;
var table = document.createElement('table');
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
var td = document.createElement('td');
body.appendChild(table);
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i +=1) {
    
    table.appendChild(tr);
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j+=1) {
        
        tr.appendChild(td);
        td.textContent = 'td';
    }
}
```

I wanted to make 3*3 table. But it made 1*1 table.

```js
var body = document.body;
var table = document.createElement('table');
body.appendChild(table);
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i +=1) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    table.appendChild(tr);
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j+=1) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.textContent = 'td';
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
}
```

And it was successfully worked. What is difference?

Comment: It's because the element is getting replaced. Imagine down the line after the for loop you try to access the `tr` elements with javascript, which `tr` belongs to which now?

The second code solves that since it creates a new `tr` element every loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the docs on [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

> The Node.appendChild() method adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node. **If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position.**

In your first code, you create *one* `tr` and *one* `td`, and then in the loops, on each iteration, you remove the `tr` and `td` from their previous locations before appending them again.

In contrast, in your second code, you're calling `createElement` on every iteration, so the new elements that the `td` and `tr` variables hold *do not exist in the document* before being appended, so nothing gets removed, and the 3x3 grid gets produced as a result.

It doesn't really have anything to do with scope - it has to do with the fact that you're creating new elements with `createElement` instead of re-using the same element you appended in a prior iteration.